# Remove duplicate element tags with same values by using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an xml in that the elements and their values are repeating. But, I want to remove duplicates by using xslt.

Below is the XML

```
<root>
<element>1</element>
<element1>2</element1>
<element>1</element>
<element3>3</element3>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<root>
<element>1</element>
<element1>2</element1>
<element3>3</element3>
</root>
```

Comment: It is a grouping problem solved many times in various ways here. Please at least tell us which version of XSLT you use or can use and also clarify whether you want to eliminate duplicates solely based on the element value (e.g. eliminate `bar` in `<foo>1></foo><bar>1</bar>`) or on element name and value.

Comment: There are nearly 2000 hits on StackOverflow for the search "XSLT Grouping". Nearly all of them have answers, and the answers are very similar. Choose the top half-a-dozen hits and you will have an answer to your question. Do bear in mind that the solution for XSLT 2.0+ is quite different (and much simpler) than the solution for XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="root">
       <xsl:element name="root">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="name()">
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
       </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
Try it
```